# Delete repeated data in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am optimizing a query in Bigquery that shows non-repeated data, currently it is like this and it works.

> `select * from (select 
>     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id) as num,
>     id,
>     created_at,
>     operator_id,
>     description
>   from NAME_TABLE
>   where created_at >='2018-01-01') where  num=1`

I wanted to ask if it is possible to make a GROUP BY with all the columns (in a simple way it cannot be done, since crated_at is not possible to group it) and keep the first data of created_at that appears for each id

PD:a DISTINCT does not work, since there are more than 80 million records (they increase 2 million per day) and it returns repeated data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY created_at LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.NAME_TABLE` t
WHERE created_at >='2018-01-01'
GROUP BY id
```

Instead of processing / returning all columns - you can specify exact list you need as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(id,created_at,operator_id,description) ORDER BY created_at LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.NAME_TABLE`
WHERE created_at >='2018-01-01'
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I think it worked (I only tried one day), I will try all the records and check again.
What does the "AS VALUE" do in the select? what's that called to read documentation

Comment: The query takes three times as long and processes twice as much data. I am trying to optimize the one I already have. I think I misspelled my question

Comment: I am not sure I follow you - you asked relatively simple and clear question - you got solution. you mentioned that you do not actually have your solution - so which one you compare with?

Comment: I think I know what you mean - check update for my answer in a minute

Answer (score 0):

You query should be fine.  But you can do this without a subquery:

```
select array_agg(nt order by created_at desc limit 1)[ordinal(1)].*
from name_table nt
where created_at >='2018-01-01'
group by id
```

Comment: I get that error :
Dot-star is not supported for type ARRAY<STRUCT<created_at TIMESTAMP

Comment: @francopina . . . Of course.  It is an array.  I fixed the answer.